# isoperimetric problem in variational methods

Tags: calculus-of-variations, constraints

I have a problem that requires to find the smallest perimeter of a curve 
that goes trough points a,b and encloses an area A between the curve and x axis.
I used the calculus of variations approach.

$$argmin_y\int_0^1 [\sqrt{1 + (y')^2}  + \alpha (y - A)] dx$$

the answer is a circle (see attached image for draw and solution).

My question is what happens when the area is to large ? obviously I can't draw a circle that goes through a,b to get that area.

is there no solution in these cases ? How can I prove it?

[Variational solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxBd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there is no solution in this case. The Euler-Lagrange equation is a necessary condition for an extremum, so if it has no solution, there's no extremum; there's nothing to prove beyond that.

The "solution" in this case is a curve with vertical segments at $a$ and $b$, connected by a circular arc. This is not a function, but it can be arbitrarily closely approximated by differentiable functions; that's why there's no extremal function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
how can I prove that vertical segments combined with a circular arc will be the optimal curve?

Comment: @DoronPor: I don't know, that was just an intuition. First you'd have to define the problem that that's the solution to, which I think would be a differentiable curve from $a$ to $b$ that stays within $[a,b]\times\mathbb R$. Then you could write the curve in parametric form, which should again yield the result that it must be circular in the interior of the region. Then you could consider arbitrary curves consisting of segments along the boundary (i.e. vertical segments) and circular arcs, and optimize with respect to the length of the segments. At the optimum the arc should be a semicircle.